# HTML Calculated Column Indicators

Tags: calculated-column

I'm trying to insert KPI indicators from the Out of the Box SharePoint images when my slippage column is at certain points, but the indicators don't seem to be showing, please can you help me with my formula:

=IF(Slippage>30,"/_layouts/images/ewr218l.gif",IF(AND(Slippage>=-7,Slippage<=-29),"/_layouts/images/ewr219l.gif",IF(AND(Slippage>=-7,Slippage<=29),"/_layouts/images/ewr219l.gif",IF(Slippage<7,"/_layouts/images/ewr217l.gif","/_layouts/images/ewr217l.gif"))))&";'>"

Comment: almost a duplicate of http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/7256/html-calculated-column-formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
="<DIV><img src='"&IF(OR(Slippage>30,Slippage<-30),"/_layouts/images/ewr218l.gif", /* s>30 or s<-30 */
   IF( OR( AND(Slippage<=-7,Slippage>=-29),AND(Slippage>=7,Slippage<=29)),
     "/_layouts/images/ewr219l.gif",  /* true, thus -29<=s<=-7 or 7<=s<=29 */
     "/_layouts/images/ewr217l.gif"   /* false, thus -7<s<7 */  
   )
 )&"'></DIV>"
```

(remove comments /*  */, spaces and linebreaks before pasting)
see also: [HTML Calculated Column Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/html-calculated-column-formula)

Comment: Hi - this is great - works really well!. How do I go about adding more lines?